# 403 Error with Search Online Validation Tools

Tags: forms

This is a really odd problem that I hope someone can help with!

On my site I have a blog, which is just a basic view of Articles. I just posted a new blog the other day and this one appears to be "invisible" to any search engine or validation tool. If I do a search for the exact title of the blog post (on Google, Bing, etc), all of the pages that are linking to the post come up, but not the post itself.

I also cannot validate the page with the Twitter Card Validator or with Google Webmaster Tools. Instead, I get a 403 Forbidden Error when those tools try to access the page.

The page *does* work when you visit it on my site or if you type the link. It's just the bots that cannot see it for some reason. It's been online for 10 days now and normally my blog posts show up within a few hours (and immediately with the validators).

I also *DID* try copying all of the HTML from the source code onto a page *OUTSIDE* of Drupal--just a static HTML file--and everything validates there. So the HTML is good...it must be something with Drupal...just don't know what!

Just wondering if anyone has experienced something similar and could point me in the right direction? Unfortunately I am not able to post a direct link to the blog here.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: By the way, using Drupal 7.22, PHP 5.3.27. I also do not have any blocked IP addresses configured.

Comment: I have had problems like those because of modules in Drupal or Apache. For example modsecurity2 will eventually send a 403 if it detects something it doesn't like...